# Storing a Function in an Object's Property

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have a JavaScript object, foo, that has a property, "bar", whose value is a function.

`var foo = {"bar" : someFunction};`

I could replace "someFunction" with an anonymous function. However, what if I wanted to define the function separately:

```
function someFunction() { 
  ...
}
```

I can't write `foo.bar = someFunction()` since it will store the result of evaluating the function.

How can I set `foo.bar`'s value to a function? How would I call it once it's set?

Comment: `foo.bar = someFunction;` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I set foo.bar's value to a function?

Without the parentheses:

```
foo.bar = someFunction;
```

---

> How would I call it once it's set?

Treat the property as you would any function:

```
foo.bar();
```

Comment: what would `foo.bar = new someFunction()` do ?

Comment: @zlomerovic that would be getting very fancy-pants with object-oriented Javascript: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript

Comment: I know that... but it seem I'd have to write it this way to get it working :) http://jsfiddle.net/7JnxF/

Comment: Even birds know that son... Have you even read what I wrote? creating a new object instance... that's what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Take out the `()` and you should be able to set it equal to a function

```
   foo.bar = someFunction; //assign
   foo.bar(); // call
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sN9cs/1/

Answer (score 1):

You should simply assign the `bar` to some `someFunction` *pointer*, like this:

```
var foo  = {};
function someFunction() {
};
foo.bar = someFunction;


foo.bar();
```

Answer (score 0):

The first example is exactly how you do it. Just don't call the function:

```
foo.bar = someFunction;
```